# React native - How to apply props on multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a button and when I toggle the button It changes the color.
This is the code:

```
state={
  status:[
    {toggle:false}
  ]
}

_onPress(){
  const newState = !this.state.toggle
  this.setState({toggle:newState})
}

render(){
      const {toggle} = this.state
      const textValue = toggle?"ON":"OFF"
      const buttonBG = toggle?"#6AAAC6":"white"
      const textColor = toggle?"white":"gray"

return(
<TouchableOpacity
onPress={()=>this._onPress()}
<Text>button</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
)
}
}
```

But what if I have multiple buttons and they basically do the same function. Is there a way I could reuse this code without copy and pasting multiple times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a component call `CustomButton`

```
class CustomButton extends React.Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    onToggle: () => {},
  }

  state = {
    status: [{ toggle: false }]
  }

  _onPress() {
    const newState = !this.state.toggle
    this.setState({ toggle: newState })
    this.props.onToggle(newState)
  }

  render() {
    const { toggle } = this.state
    const textValue = toggle ? 'ON' : 'OFF'
    const buttonBG = toggle ? '#6AAAC6' : 'white'
    const textColor = toggle ? 'white' : 'gray'

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPress()}>
        <Text>button</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}
```

and use anywhere you want

```
class App extends React.Component {

  onButtonToggle = (isToggle) => {
    console.log(isToggle)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <CustomButton onToggle={this.onButtonToggle} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong. I am getting an error "Can't find variable: callBackForTooggle". Where is the "callBackForToggle" in the code?

Comment: `callBackForTooggle` is just a name of your function. It use for you want do something when CustomButton is toggle.

Comment: I am new to react native. I would really appreciate if you could show me an example.